# Sitecore MultiLanguage Content changes the URL. Results 404, Not found error

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor, multilingual, sitecore-api

I'm having an issue in my site.I'm using VirtualFolder property to change the site language content. I've a link 'Environment' and my default site language is Chinese. So,the URL looks like www.xyz.com/environment when I switch to English URL becomes www.xyz.com/en/environment but the problem here is when I again switch to Chinese language it strips the URL with '/en' So the URL becomes www.xyz.com/vironment which results the 404 not found error. Changing the Virtualfolder value solves the issue but I was looking for the permanent solution so that in future I may have link with any name.

I tried changing the value of 'Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage' to false but didn't solve the issue for me.
Can anyone suggest me something.

Thanks

Comment: You're not supposed to use virtual folders to embed languages in your URL like that. It will work out of the box.